# DevExpress - Xtra Reports: VB.NET How to get current page number?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, xtrareport

I've searched their site. I just want to find the page number in the vb script. I have a report header, and if it is on page #1 then I want a page break after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do the trick.  It's the PrintOnPage event handler for a label in your Report Header.

```
Private Sub xrLabel1_PrintOnPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.PrintOnPageEventArgs) Handles xrLabel1.PrintOnPage
   If e.PageIndex > 0 Then
      ReportHeader.PageBreak = DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.PageBreak.None
   Else
      ReportHeader.PageBreak = DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.PageBreak.AfterBand
   End If
End Sub
```

Note that the PageIndex value is zero-indexed.  Also, the page index is only available (as far as I know) in the PrintOnPageEventArgs, so this won't work in a Before/AfterPrint event.

See [this knowledge base article for reference.](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A2630.aspx)